# Setuptex.bat missing when installing ConTeXt on Windows

Tags: installing, context, windows

I've been having a hard time installing ConTeXt on Windows. I'm following the ConTeXt Garden instructions (http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone#Windows) so I download and extract context-setup-win64.zip, navigate to it in cmd and then run first-setup.bat, resulting in the following message:

[image: ConTeXt setup message]

But I don't seem to have `tex\setuptex.bat` or `tex\texmf-win64` at all. I've also tried installing ConTeXt in various other ways (by getting TeX Live or installing ConTeXt on the Ubuntu subsystem for Windows) but I haven't had anything compile successfully yet. I'm somewhat familiar with LaTeX but I'm not the best at TeX in general so sorry if this is an obvious question, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the files present in `C:\ConTeXt\context\tex` directory (ideal would be the output of `dir` inside that directory).

Comment: Are sure that you DID unzip (extract) the files and not only open them ? This is a common error with windows zip filer.